# Custom URL for sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, url

I have been reading around that it is not possible to change the default Sharepoint Site Collection Url eg. `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/` to something like `http://mycompany.com`. Is this still true at the moment? If yes, is there another way of providing a better name instead of the default one?

I was thinking about redirect but that is not professional at all. Any solution to this cumbersome problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What @[bonm014](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/17155/bonm014) said is true: it's not possible. The Microsoft's User Voice channel is the source for requested features and their status. [Changing the tenant's name](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/10285887-make-is-possible-to-change-tenant-name-in-office36) is one of the often requested additions, and it's current status is not implemented. Microsoft hasn't also added a status for the request (such as "thinking about it" or "working on it"), so there's no reason to currently wait this to be implemented.

As others at the given link have stated, it has become necessary to find an alternative when changing the URL has become a required matter. Real-life workarounds tend to be a set up of a new environment and migrating to it.

Comment: moe, thanks for your answer, but could you please explain what you mean by "... set up a new environment and migrate to it"? Do you mean that I have to create another tenant? If yes, that does not answer my question above. I don't want to have `".sharepoint.com"` in my url.

Comment: @BurreIfort that would exactly be creating a new tenant. However, you can't really get rid of the `".sharepoint.com"`. It's there, it's part of the product. A mild compromise for this has been described [here at SO.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30461782/3181315), but 1) it's a complicated solution, and 2) it's just a trick.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible, except for building a new tenant with the correct url/name.
This is the reason a lot of migration needs to take place within SharePoint Online.

Comment: If you have any reference to add to support your answer, that would be great.

Comment: It is an old request, but still not updated

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Is-it-possible-to-rename-base-Tenant-naming/td-p/23994

Comment: It seems like the uservoice-link referenced there would be the primary source to keep an eye on this:  https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/10285887-make-is-possible-to-change-tenant-name-in-office36